# MySQL UPDATE query, is this wrong?

Tags: php, mysql

been working all day on something and can't seem to get this right...

I have a key generation script in PHP that runs some if statements, selects a license, creates a key, inserts it into the database and then emails the user the output.

The key is inserting into the database fine, and the email even sends fine with the key in it.  The variable for email is $email, and is declared at this point, because it gets used down below this query to send an email (which sends).  However, I can't get this UDPATE query to work in between the two (yes, the key is already generated and inserted by now):

```
$username = $email;
mysql_query("UPDATE keys SET username='".$username."' WHERE key='".$userkey."'");
```

Username is varchar, 255.

HELP!

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Sweet Jesus, SQL injection ahoy... http://www.bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @David How presumptuous, and insulting! Where do you see a SQL injection issue? You don't know the origin of $username or $userkey or if they've been escaped or not. Concatenating variables into a SQL query does not automatically imply any SQL injection vulnerability exists.

Comment: It's possible that the user escaped them beforehand; quite probably not though, I'd suspect, and any example showing variables being interpolated into a query without demonstrating they're safe encourages more and more people to create SQL injection vulnerabilities, hence I feel the need to draw attention to it.

Comment: Would paypal verifying the information after a payment notification count as being safe enough?  Might be worthwhile to add all the information is coming directly from PayPal's IPN service, all the variables have been declared from POST_ off their request, and they're only declared once PayPal double checks the IPN request to stop fake submissions

Comment: As you can't set your PayPal account e-mail to be a SQL query, you're perfectly safe in this instance.

Comment: Awesome Dan, thanks a ton for answering the questions and helping out.  This site rocks.  Took me an hour and I couldn't figure it out (even though I knew that, slipped my mind!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KEY` is a reserved word in MySQL (e.g. `PRIMARY KEY`).

If you're going to use it as an identifier, you will have to surround the name with `backticks` in every query.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `keys` SET username='".$username."' WHERE `key`='".$userkey."'");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Copied and pasted your code in but it's still not updating.  Hmm, and the username value can't be empty... this is blowing my mind.

Comment: Add backticks around `keys` too.

Comment: aha well thank you very much, been going 18 hours and I guess it just slipped my mind.  Appreciate it, and to those guys saying SQL injection - I don't think so, because this code is only executed when a certain condition is already met, after a paypal IPN has been received, sent back, validated, returned, and this is within a nested if statement... but I'm not a security expert, so...

Answer (score 1):

Both `key` and `keys` are reserved words in MySQL. You need to escape both with backticks:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `keys` SET username='".$username."' WHERE `key`='".$userkey."'");
```